# Code not echoing "ok"

Tags: php, database, authentication, hash

I have been searching for ages and I'm stuck again, my code is not echoing "ok" when I put the right password in for the user that matches the password in the database.

Everything else works fine, I'm not sure if I've missed anything silly out; I probably have, so apologies for being dumb :)

**PHP:**

```
class User {
    private $_db, $data;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem registering');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                echo 'ok';
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your PHP logs?

Comment: It seems that either you are using different hash functions for registration and logging in or your credentials are wrong after all.

Answer (score 1):

On your `login()` , you have to rewrite like this..

```
 public function login($username = null, $password = null) {

        $user = $this->find($username);


        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                //echo 'ok';
                return true;   
            }

        }
        else { return false; }
    }
```

Comment out the `echo` and return true from there instead. So you will be callingyour function from your instance like

```
if($someinst->find('someuser'))
      {
         echo "User Found";
      }
else { echo "Not Found"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to catch your problem:

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null)
{
    $user = $this->find($username);

    if($user) {
        if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
            echo 'User and password Ok!';            
        } else {
            echo 'User and password do not match'; // Handle it
        }
    } else {
        echo 'User not found'; // Handle it
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, at a first view, this could be the problem:

```
$this->data()->password
```

maybe you shoud use something like:

```
if($user->password === Hash::make($password ...
```